# How do I get ActionBarCompat to show the normal default icon (set in the application/intent-filter android:icon attribute in the manifest)?

Tags: android

Any clues on how to get ActionBarCompat to show the default icon in pre-honeycomb devices the normal honeycomb/ics action bar would show? i.e. the icon set in the `<application>`/`<intent-filter>` `android:icon` attribute in the manifest.

Also information on how to get the resource ID for the android:icon would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, for pre-Honeycomb, you'll have to change the icon referenced by the 'HOME' ActionBar element in `ActionBarHelperBase.java` class. This should be somewhere in the `setupActionBar()` method, like so:

```
homeItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
```

Just change this to

```
homeItem.setIcon(R.drawable.launcher);
```

and you should be good to go. For changing in Honeycomb, you'll need to change the `android:icon` attributes in `values-v11\styles.xml` in the style for `ActionBar`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> > > Also information on how to get the resource ID for the android:icon would be helpful.

What? If you use: `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` then the resource id is `R.drawable.ic_launcher`.

Also, you mention `ActionBarCompat`... are you using ActionBarSherlock? if so it should show that icon by default. What are you seeing instead?

Comment: I'm using the ActionBarCompat api example as a library in my project. it all works except that in ActionBarCompat for pre-honeycomb devices it manually sets the icon to `ic_home`. I thought I could change that code to read the resource id for whatever is set in the app manifest.

Comment: Ahh, I got it. In that case let me recommend you to use ActionBarSherlock ;)